# Can Visual Studio display an Intel disassembly instead of AT&T syntax during a Linux-GCC-Debug session?

Tags: c, assembly, visual-studio-debugging, disassembly, intel-syntax

Currently the disassembly shows AT&T syntax below, but I'm accustomed to reading the Intel syntax.
Is there an option or setting to switch between them? Thanks.

[image: intel]

Comment: The format it's using looks like standard GNU binutils disassembly (used by `objdump` and GDB), so likely it's possible to set an option equivalent to `objdump -Mintel -drwC`.  (Or if not, it would be easy for MS to add such an option, because the library does already support a MASM-like flavour of Intel syntax, like GAS with `.intel_syntax noprefix` understands.  A now-deleted comment suggested there was no such option; IDK I don't use Visual Studio.)

Comment: It seems the syntax is default and may be related to the debugger. I also didn’t find an option to change the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Before `disassemble main` you should change the syntex to intel.
For changing to intel syntex from at&t, use this command to change `set disassembly intel`. [Refer here, I shared an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkfBS.png)

Comment: The code is running within Visual Studio, not gdb.